# Perl DBI select providing wrong values using bind_columns

Tags: mysql, perl, crypt

I have this Perl code:

```
my $cmd = "
  SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM tblUsers
  WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER(?) AND password = ?
";

db_connect();
my $sql = $dbh->prepare($cmd);

my $count = 2;

$sql->execute(
  $args{login_username},
  crypt($args{login_password}, $args{login_username})
) or die "SQL Error: ".$sql->errstr;

$sql->bind_columns(\$count);
$sql->fetch;
```

which is returning 0, but should be returning a 1

If I output the following:

```
$msg = "wrong username/password: $count;$args{login_username};$args{login_password};" . crypt($args{login_password}, $args{login_username});
```

I get:

```
wrong username/password: 0;skeniver;password;skh9dtk2bCasY
```

and the `crypt` part is exactly what I have in the database. Running the same values in MySQL returns a count of 1.

I really can't figure out what's going wrong here.

Does anyone else see something I'm missing?

Comment: Try `$count = $sql->fetchrow_array();` instead of `$sql->bind_columns(\$count); $sql->fetch;` and see what the results of `$count` are.

Comment: Which driver are you using? Is this a MySQL database?

Comment: Dare I suggest you do some debugging? Remove the `AND password = ?` from the statement and see if that works. Remove the calls to `upper` and try `WHERE username = ?`. See what works and what doesn't ...

Comment: ($count) = $sql->fetchrow_array();
also returns 0

Comment: and bizarrely, removing the AND password = ? line and the parameters in the $sql->execute causes an error...

Becoming a pain this

Comment: Be systematic. Start without a `bind_columns` and execute `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tblUsers` and see what happens. Then add `WHERE` conditions one by one until it breaks

Comment: can you do a `TRIM(password) = ?;` (and possibly on the `username` as well)

Comment: Using just SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tblUsers gives the massive error: Error executing run mode 'login': Can't locate auto/DBI/db=HASH(0x9dece94).al in @INC ---------- Thanks all, but I'm gonna give up for tonight

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `select` returns a non `0` value and assuming that the column `password` in `tblUsers` has `skh9dtk2bCasY` for `username`=`skeniver`, Try

```
 $sql->execute($args{login_username}, crypt($args{login_password},$args{login_username}))
        or die "SQL Error: ".$sql->errstr;
 $count = $sql->fetchrow_array();
```

Or, if there is a possibility that the query returns multiple rows then-

```
$sql->execute($args{login_username}, crypt($args{login_password},$args{login_username}))
        or die "SQL Error: ".$sql->errstr;
while (($count) = $sql->fetchrow_array()){                          
    print "Count is: $count\n"; 
}
```

Comment: The SQL is `SELECT count(id)...`. Is that a multi-row query?

Comment: I have no idea if that's a multirow query. My assumption would be NO its not. But then I am skeptical about the entire query itself (i.e. the `WHERE...AND` clause).

Comment: without a `GROUP BY` it's just counting the number of matches of the `WHERE` clause. One row with one column